# AngularJs: Get notified when DOM is changed by a 3rd party library(Knockout)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

We are switching from Knockout to AngularJs. While we cannot finish it in very shot time, I have to find a way to have both live together. There are many cases, I need to notify AngularJs that KO has changed the dom and please update your ng-model accordingly. Currently, I am using `$('#id').trigger('change')`, which I do not think is good. Is there a better way to notify AngularJs about this change. I am composing a jsfiddle, but having too little knowledge on KO, I will add it later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("body").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
});
```

Here you can find some info: http://davidwalsh.name/dom-events-javascript

Comment: I feel that is overkill. It is even more expensive than my solution.  Btw, is it cross-browser?

Comment: Not sure about cross-browser. I think, it works only on browsers with html5 support